# Does AzureReader2 pull the image from the cdn if a query string is attached?

Tags: imageresizer

I think I need some explanation on this.  On this page:http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/unfiltered-product/bd/BDGTPD/bully-dog-gt-platinum-diesel, you will see the following images:

[image]

The 2 on the left don't have any query strings and are located at:

http://stage.bullydog.com/azure/bdgtpd/40420_1.png and http://stage.bullydog.com/azure/bdgtpd/40420_4.png

On the third image, I put a query string of ?w=500 and that is located at:

http://stage.bullydog.com/azure/bdgtpd/40420_5.png?w=500

Her is a capture of the network traffic when I requested the page that contained the images:

[image]

Here is where I need some clarification and overall what is happening here:

1. If the image url contains a query string, does it pull the image from the azure cdn?  I noticed the image `40420_5.png?w=500` has a `Request Url` of `http://stage.bullydog.com/azure/bdgtpd/40420_5.png?w=500`, so it doesn't appear to be pulling from the azure cdn.  Why is this?
2. For the other images, take `40420_4` for example, I noticed it issues a 302 first and then another request.  Why does it do this?
3. If using srcset, is ImageResizer beneficial here, for example, is it better to set the different sources with the query string attached, such as `40420_5.png?w=250, 40420_5.png?w=500, etc` or is it better to just create the different image sizes such as `40420_5_w250.png, 40420_5_w500.png`? or maybe Slimmage with SlimResponse would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzureReader2 will issue a redirect to Azure if processing isn't required. Otherwise, your browser will *not* be able to see that AzureReader2 is making an HTTP request in the background to fetch the source resource. Your URLs should always point to the ImageResizer server.

Srcset + ImageResizer is great. Most people use it with the `w=[value]` and `zoom=[value]` querystring commands.

Comment: I understand the part about redirecting to azure if processing is not required, that makes sense now.  What is the difference between using `w` and `width` and what is the reason why people would use `zoom`?  Do  you know what is the best way to determine these values?  There is a lot of info online, but it is not as easy to understand.

Comment: One other question, correct me if I am wrong.  If the image has a query string, is it fetched from the azure cdn first and then processed or is it processed from the local image folder in the web project for example and with clientCache, does it cache it on the azure server or is it cached locally?

Comment: That depends on how you've configured things. Do you understand how a CDN or reverse proxy works?

Comment: To be honest... Not really... Especially a reverse proxy

Comment: A [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) acts as a proxy to another server (the "origin" server, which should be ImageResizer). So you don't "store" or "fetch" things on a CDN, unless you're conflating the concept with blob storage.